# How to know the fields of a loaded data

Tags: vega-lite

I have loaded some data from a csv with:

```
var data = {"url": "mydata.csv"}
```

which works perfectly in an further embedding like:

```
vegaEmbed('#graph', {
    $schema: 'https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json',
    "data": data,
    "mark": ...,
    "encoding": {...}
}
```

Is there a way to know the names of the columns of my csv ?
For example, to use them in the encodings.

When I try to inspect the `data` with the developer tools, it seems the data contains a definition and not -- or not yet -- the content of the data (which by the way it perfectly logic).

Answer (score 1):

To get the data from view, you can use the vega view API as `view.data("source_0")`.
Refer the documentation for more details:  https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/#view_data

Steps:

1. Open the example in [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemhBQ5mJDVlwATooxwaZLGgBMYgAxK1SPWlAMjgrU70EoSIxBSMvIAvkrIRgDWWkz+pnCyOmoGZK4gAB5pAGY0cIJqWgDyRhYGIGEgAJ5pSGRkRnyYcFo6DLKYpph0gs3oAHIMCEzGAARsWSMAwv4Q5SEhQA).
2. Open your console and provide the following: `VEGA_DEBUG.view.data('source_0')`.

This will return the data with its fields.
In your case, you might not be able to use `VEGA_DEBUG`. So refer this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Wahab896/ae7wvfx4/7/) example and check the console.

Comment: A minimal working example would be appreciated : ```Uncaught ReferenceError: view is not defined```

Comment: And if I follow the doc : ```new vega.View(runtime,...``` this time it is _runtime_ which is unknown.

Comment: I have updated the answer and let me know if that work. Check the vega-editor as well as jsfiddle.

Comment: It works in the sense that it gives me the data, but it still does not gives me the names of the columns. Admittedly is not that difficult but contradicts the claim that "Vega-Lite uses _tabular_ data" .

Comment: You can just use the data at 0th position and get the keys which will be your column name. Also it is a tabular data, if you check the vega-editor and see the `Data Viewer` below the chart section, then you will see your data in tabular form.

Comment: Thanks Wahab, that's what I meant by "not difficult to do". And the Vega editor is a marvel. However, I disagree with the word tabular. The data is a list/array of objects indexed by comumn name. A tabular organisation would be a metadata containg the columns names (possibly other column info like type, format,...) and the data as a list/array of list. Nervertheless, Vega is a jewel.