# vega-lite: how to set responsive width using facet?

Tags: vega-lite

In [this page](https://ondata.github.io/covid19italia/terapiaintensiva/) I have two charts, a single one and a facet one.

[This is](https://github.com/ondata/covid19italia/blob/master/docs/terapiaintensiva/spec/terapieIntensiveN.json) the config for the first in which I have set `"width": "container"` and I have a **responsive width** for this one.

[This is](https://github.com/ondata/covid19italia/blob/master/docs/terapiaintensiva/spec/terapieIntensiveR.json) the second config file. I have 3 columns. If I set in it `"width": "container"` it is the **single graph** of a column **that fits** the width of the container, **not the three columns together**.

Is there any way to **make** it **responsive** in relation to the **width** of **the three columns together**?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can provide `width: container` to facet charts as it might not support. I can clearly see warnings in logs: `[Warning] Width "container" only works for single views and layered views.`

As I understand your issue, you are unable get the full width of above chart (single view chart). You can try the following for that:

1. Provide `autosize` in above chart:

   `"autosize": {"contains": "padding", "resize": true, "type": "fit"}`
2. Another workaround is you can get the width of `facet` chart, once its rendered and then try to set the `width` of single chart programmatically using [Vega Api](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/#view_width):

   `view.width(1000).run()`

To test this in vega editor, use `VEGA_DEBUG` to access view: `VEGA_DEBUG.view.width(1800).run()`

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thank you. The first does not work, for the second I must study :) I will try to do it

Comment: Where is VEGA_DEBUG  in Vega Editor?

Comment: In the console you will find VEGA_DEBUG.

Comment: You can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67009907/7734100) for more details of how to use VEGA_DEBUG or how to get view.

Comment: Thank you. If I run  `view.width(1000).run()` in this page, I have `Uncaught ReferenceError: view is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1` https://ondata.github.io/covid19italia/terapiaintensiva/

Comment: Check the fiddle attached in that answer. You will get the view from vegaEmbed. View is directly not available, you need to store it in some variable, if you see in that fiddle it is stored in view.

Comment: Hi, I have added the variable here https://github.com/ondata/covid19italia/blob/master/docs/terapiaintensiva/js/config.js#L33-L36 but in the console, in this page, I have always `Uncaught ReferenceError: view is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1` https://ondata.github.io/covid19italia/terapiaintensiva/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232321/discussion-between-wahab-memon-and-aborruso).

Comment: From [vega-light documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/size.html#limitations):

The view must be either a single view or a layered view. **Fit does not work with** other kinds of composed views ( **facet** /hconcat/vconcat/repeat).